# Windows Invalidated after GParted partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my computer on a tiny 20 GB Partition. I decided this was far too small, so I used GParted, resized the partition to an 80 GB partition, and Reinstalled the GRUB bootloader.

However, the next time I booted back into Windows, I was told

> You may be a victim of software counterfeiting.

I tried activating using my Windows 7 product key (Which I couldn't get from the installation disk, because the computer was given to me by a friend, I used WinKeyFinder 2) but it's telling me "Your computer is not yet activated with genuine windows key."

I know this is incorrect because my computer was working properly just a few weeks ago! I talked to Microsoft support but they were no help. Now, I'm at my wits end trying to validate this product key because I want to install 64 Bit Windows on my computer, but I have no valid product key!

Comment: You made a big enough change that Windows can't be sure if it was cloned or something, hence the re-activation. It's definitely very very annoying, I've been there before. Suffice to say, all Windows instances I run are VMs.

Comment: What exactly did Microsoft say?  Was it the activation group you contacted to do a phone activation?

Comment: I chatted with the answer desk (didn't have time to talk on the phone") the guy told me my product key was invalid.

Comment: Your friend probably gave you a fake or pirated copy of Windows. This isn't really your fault, but if I got a computer from someone else and it had a non-genuine copy of Windows on it, I would wipe the system and just install Linux on it. **If someone gave me a computer with Windows preinstalled, I'd make sure it's genuine Windows before proceeding any further.**

Comment: I'm reinstalling Windows Vista. That's the copy of Windows that came with my computer, and I'm using the product key that is on the bottom of the laptop.